# Modify margins above a UWP TabView

Tags: c#, uwp, winui

I'm trying to modify the margin that exists above the tabs in a [TabView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tab-view) control, see the little red arrow here:

[image]

I think this margin is set [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/347c4bd18f2fc6832f100050f18f95a661c1c8fc/dev/TabView/TabView.xaml#L297) (its the matching amount of offset), but my attempts to modify this value via setters haven't been successful. How do I change it?

Edit: [Looks like](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3736) the method to modify this may change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding/margin you want to modify is controlled by the lightweight styling resource "TabViewHeaderPadding", overriding it with your desired value will change the margin as desired. Following XAML will show the result below:

```xml
<muxc:TabView>
    <muxc:TabView.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="TabViewHeaderPadding">0,20,0,0</Thickness>
    </muxc:TabView.Resources>
</muxc:TabView>
```

[image: Updated padding image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following steps as a sample:

1. Open the **Document Outline** pane and find your `TabView` control.
2. Right-click the `TabView` control and select the option **Edit Template > Edit a Copy**, then a default style of the `TabView` control will be applied.
3. Find the `TabViewListView` control named `TabListView` in the added default style.
4. Add the `Margin` property, like this: `Margin="0,10,0,0"`

If you need to set the Add button’s `Margin`, you could add a `Margin` property of the `AddButton` control in the style.

Comment: This allowed me to increase the margin, but unfortunately did not allow me to reduce the margin.